# playframework enumerator a rolling file content as string got strange chars

Tags: scala, playframework, loops

```
def buildLog(appName: String) = {
  val file = s"${sys.env("HOME")}/builds/logs/${appName}.log"
  val f = new File(file)
  Enumerator.fromFile(f).map(new String(_))
}
```

I want to display a rolling log file to the web page, I use `Enumerator.fromFile()` method and map the byte array to String, but I am getting some strange chars like

```
From xxx:yyy/zzz
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mLoading project definition from /home/zzz/builds/sources/ops-ui/project[0m
[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mSet current project to zzz (in build file:/home/zzz/builds/sources/ops-ui/)[0m
[0m[[32msuccess[0m] [0mTotal time: 0 s, completed 2013-12-30 17:38:53[0m
```

How to display the content correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those characters define colors the console should use to display the text (e.g. info in cyan and errors in red).

To remove the characters from your file, you can [change the logging configuration](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SettingsLogger), for example replace `%coloredLevel` with `%level` in *conf/logger.xml*.

Alternatively, you could implement a custom `LogManager` to rewrite logs as needed. This is inspired by similar [emojiLogs](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/22d47a09fdf412a86c2ac86da3eb0633b60169ea/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlaySettings.scala#L275), but *I did not test it*:

```
logManager ~= { lm =>
  new LogManager {
    def apply(
        data: sbt.Settings[Scope],
        state: State,
        task: Def.ScopedKey[_],
        writer: java.io.PrintWriter
    ) = {
      val l = lm.apply(data, state, task, writer)
      new Logger {
        val Escapes = Set("M\\\\[2K", "\\[0m", "\\[32m")
        def ommitColorChars(str: String) = Escapes.fold(str)(_.replaceAll(_))
        def log(level: Level.Value, message: => String) =
          l.log(level, ommitColorChars(message))
        def success(message: => String) = l.success(message)
        def trace(t: => Throwable) = l.trace(t)
        override def ansiCodesSupported = l.ansiCodesSupported
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thansk， I just replace that chars to empty string, for my case
`val Escapes = Set("M\\\\[2K", "\\[0m", "\\[32m")
  def ommitColorChars(str: String) = Escapes.fold(str)(_.replaceAll(_))`

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete a bit more the answer, I found a more general way of removing coloured logs. The colouring characters can be removed as (assuming you have a string with the coloured logs):

```
string.replaceAll("""\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]""", "")
```

Inspired by the equivalent "sed" in Linux command ([1](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed)):

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
```